# Calculating Sample Moments in R (raw code)

Tags: r

I'm trying to code functions that will calculate sample moments around 0 and around the mean, from the 1st order to the 4th order. I got the first one down, but I am having trouble with the second. Here's my code:

```
moment.zero <- function(x) {
  lapply(1:4, function(i) (1/length(x$elements)) * sum(x$elements^i))
}

moment.mean <- function(x) {
  lapply(1:4, function(i) (1/length(x$elements)) * sum(x$elements #mistake is here - mean(x$elements))^i)
}
```

I am not supposed to use loops, so I used the lapply function. I can't figure out the code for the sample moment around the mean; I need to access each individual element in the list, subtract it from the mean, then raise it to the appropriate power. Using indices did not help, so my main question is: how does one refer to each element within a list?

Comment: There is a [moments package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/moments/index.html) on CRAN...or does the phrase "I am not supposed to use loops" suggest this is homework?

Answer (score 1):

```
moment.zero <- function(x) {
  n <- length(x)
  sapply(1:4, function(i) (1/n) * sum(x^i))
}

moment.mean <- function(x) {
  mu <- mean(x)
  n <- length(x)
  sapply(1:4, function(i) (1/n) * sum((x - mu)^i))
}
```

Note that calculating `mu` and `n` up front is a (minor) efficiency improvement - otherwise they are calculated four times.

To reference elements of a vector use square brackets: e.g. `x[2]`.

Comment: Thanks - that worked. Weird. I tried that, but it didn't yield the right answer.

Comment: What results are you expecting? If you are really after sample moments, you will probably want to use `n-1` rather than `n`. Note I've have switched to `sapply` to return vectors rather than lists.

Comment: Well, I just tested out my code using the functions available in the moments package. The first code yielded the correct answers, but the second one didn't. However, after that simple fix, my answers correspond to those calculated using the functions in the moments package. Thanks!